# GDAL (batch) compress .tif in place

Tags: gdal, batch

I have a project where people are generating .tifs. Unfortunately, they often forget to compress, which results in unnecessarily huge files. Compressing them one by one is a tedious process, also since the datanames shouldn't change. When trying to compress "in place" (i.e. overwriting the original file), GDAL complains that source and target dataset have to be different.

Is there an efficient way to mass compress .tifs in place?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any option for gdal_translate to modify data "in place" (same result [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/414939/gdal-translate-deletes-gtiff-instead-of-overwriting)). However you can use a batch script to process the files, create a temporary output, delete the original file and then rename the temporary output to the original file name, e.g.:

```
gdal_translate -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" "input_file.tif" "temp.tif"
del "input_file.tif"
ren "temp.tif" "input_file.tif"
```

I created a script that can be called from the command line to do exactly this, see code [here](https://github.com/Hannes-Ole/utility_gis/blob/main/BATCH/gdal_compressTIFS.bat). It can be easily adapted to other gdal commands, or [this version](https://github.com/Hannes-Ole/utility_gis/blob/main/BATCH/gdal_command_to_folder.bat) allows to pass the gdal command (or any other command) as an argument (and does compression by default):

```
@echo off
rem "compressTIFS.bat"
rem >> compressTIFS.bat directory_input [directory_output] [-r]

rem Loop over folder with .tifs and compress files either in place (default) or to a new folder (keeping the folder structure, if recursing)

rem USAGE examples:
rem 1) Default
rem     compressTIFS.bat C:\data 
rem 2) In place with recursion to subdirs
rem     compressTIFS.bat C:\data "" -r
rem 3) To output dir with recursion to subdirs
rem     compressTIFS.bat C:\data C:\data_compressed -r

rem DEPENDENCIES:
rem 1) GDAL - the command GDAL_TRANSLATE must be found on PATH
rem     this can be achieved by running this bat file within the OSGeo4W shell
rem     or manually adding GDAL to PATH

rem author: Hannes Horneber
rem v2023.04
rem based on this script: https://gist.github.com/percursoaleatorio/5293340

echo -------------------------
echo Start Batch TIF Compression
echo Processing directory: %1

if "%~1" == "" goto errorInput
if not exist "%1" goto errorDir

set inplace=false
set recurse=false
if "%~2" == "-r" (
    set recurse=true
) else (
    if "%~2" == "" (
        echo Output dir not specified... compressing in place using temp files
        set inplace=true
    ) else (
        echo Output directory: "%~2"
        if not exist "%~2" (
            mkdir "%~2"
            echo Output dir doesn't exist ... created.
        )
    )
)

if "%~3" == "-r" (
    echo Recursive processing is enabled
    set recurse=true
)

echo -------------------------

rem define gdal command. can also be used for other commands (here we only compress)
set gdal_cmd=gdal_translate -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE"

if %recurse%==true (
  echo Processing directory recursively
  for /r "%1" %%i in (*.tif) do (
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "file=%%i"
    if "!file:~-4!" == ".tif" (
      rem get relative path and filename without extension .tif
      set "rel_fname=!file:%~1=!"
      set "rel_fname=!rel_fname:~0,-4!"
      rem get filename without extension
      set "fname=%%~ni"
      set "outdir=%~2!folder!"
      if not exist "!outdir!" mkdir "!outdir!"
      echo Processing %%i
      if %inplace%==true (
        %gdal_cmd% "%%i" "%1!rel_fname!_temp.tif"
        echo Deleting temp file and renaming.
        del "%%i"
        echo ren "%1!rel_fname!_temp.tif" "!fname!.tif"
        ren "%1!rel_fname!_temp.tif" "!fname!.tif"
      ) else (
        if exist "!outdir!\!fname!.tif" (
          echo WARNING Output file "!outdir!\!fname!.tif" already exists... skipping.
        ) else (
          %gdal_cmd% "%%i" "!outdir!\!fname!.tif"
        )
      )
      endlocal
    )
  )
) else (
  echo Processing directory non-recursively
  for %%i in ("%~1\*.tif") do (
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "fname=%%~ni"
    echo Processing %%i
    if %inplace%==true (
      %gdal_cmd% "%%i" "%~1\!fname!_temp.tif"
      echo Deleting temp file and renaming.
      del "%%i"
      echo ren "%~1\!fname!_temp.tif" "!fname!.tif"
      ren "%~1\!fname!_temp.tif" "!fname!.tif"
    ) else (
      if exist "%~2\!fname!.tif" (
        echo WARNING Output file "%~2\!fname!.tif" already exists... skipping.
      ) else (
        %gdal_cmd% "%%i" "%~2\!fname!.tif"
      )
    )
    endlocal
  )
)

goto :end

:errorDir
echo ERROR Input directory doesn't exist... exiting.
goto :end
:errorInput
echo ERROR Input directory isn't specified ... exiting.
goto :end
:end
echo -------------------------
```